# How to change view after Touchid

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have touchID identification to open my app. If this return access correct, go to other view Controller. But when I pass authentication, half of the screen is black and touchID view is also shown.

I use:

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let controller3 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view1") as UIViewController
  self.presentViewController(controller3, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How can do this correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing more of your code/approach, it is hard to be certain. But if you are calling any UI code in the reply block of the LAContext "evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply", you need to put all UI code in the main thread.

Per Apple docs, the method "asynchronously evaluates an authentication policy" and the reply block "is evaluated on a private queue internal to the framework in an unspecified threading context."

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/LAContext/evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply: